# How to change behaviour of str(aList) in python

Tags: string, python-2.7

I'm trying to extract information from a very large XML file by parsing it with a python(v2.7.10) script. The goal is to make this information available to my other project written in C as (very large) array and integer literals in a file.
The following code demonstrates what I'm doing:

```
import sys

myList = [[1,2,3],[11,22,33]]
size = len(myList)
print("int myList[" + str(size) + "][3] = " + str(myList) + ";\n")
```

The result of this is `int myList[2][3] = [[1,2,3],[11,22,33]];`, but what I need is C syntax: `int myList[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{11,22,33}};`

Is there a way to modify `str()` in a way that it uses `{}` instead of `[]` for printing lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **translate table `trans`** for that, and then use the **`str.translate(..)` function**:

```
from string import maketrans

trans = maketrans('[]','{}')
print("int myList[" + str(size) + "][3] = " + str(myList).translate(trans) + ";\n")
```

This then prints:

```
>>> from string import maketrans
>>> myList = [[1,2,3],[11,22,33]]
>>> size = len(myList)
>>> trans = maketrans('[]','{}')
>>> print("int myList[" + str(size) + "][3] = " + str(myList).translate(trans) + ";\n")
int myList[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {11, 22, 33}};
```

But note that if the elements are not lists, this can result in content that is not semantically valid. We simply replace `'['` by `'{'`, and `']'` by `'}'`.

Comment: I get `AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'maketrans'` , it seems like its not an attribute in python 2.7.10 but valid in python 3

Comment: @Human: In Python-2, you need an import statement, and use the imported function.